# Use Amazon alexa or Google home compatible hardware without alexa/Google home

Tags: http, hardware, alexa-skills-kit, google-home, google-smart-home

There are plenty of devices available, which are promoted with the phrase "compatible with alexa/google home", e.g. [LightBulb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074VWLY1J) or [Smart socket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071L1CXKV)

**My question is:**
Is it somehow possible to use and control these devices **without using alexa or Google home**? I'm specifically asking for WiFi devices like smart light bulbs or sockets. I would like to just **connect them to my WiFi** and then control them by **sending some kind of HTTP-request** to the devices, without using any alexa or google cloud whatsoever.

In my opinion if the devices are all compatible with these cloud-based services, they have to share some common API, which I should also be able to use offline just in my network, should'nt I?
Unfortunately I did not find any information about such an API that I could use.
Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're actually asking "do smart home devices have a local API that devices like Alexa and Google Home use?" With the implication that you can then take advantage of them as well.

While some might - the general answer is "no".

Neither Alexa nor Google Home control devices directly. Both of them send their commands to their cloud services, which relay the command to a device manufacturers cloud endpoint, which then relays the specific instruction to the device or the device's local hub or gateway.

Comment: Ok, that is what I was afraid of. So if I correctly understand it, every manufacturer has an own protocol between the device and the own cloud service (which is also used for alexa compatibility, because alexa triggers/uses this cloud service), and maybe also an own protocol to control the device in a local network with an own (non-alexa) app.

Comment: That is correct. Many also use the cloud-device protocol for phone apps as well, since this means they won't need to build two protocols. There **are** local protocols implemented by **some** devices, but there is no single standard.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer! do you have a hint for me how to find devices with a local protocol (that i can use for my own application)? I have no clue how to find them in the multitude of existing alexa-hardware.

Comment: Don't search for things that advertize Alexa/Home compatibility. Search the various Maker and hardware forums for what they're suggesting and using.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to command your Google Home compatible devices with your voice, you can simply use the Google Home app from your phone (both iOS or Android) without having the Google Home device.